# How to extract public and private part from p8 Apple APN certificate?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, vapor

In some reason I need to extract `public` and `private` keys from Apple `p8` certificate. Any idea how?

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, no but I can lead you through it quickly; the `p8` file is not private key, it's both keys together (somehow) actually, so to get both private and public keys out of it, on my local machine I let VaporAPNS load the `p8` file and added a breakpoint to `VaporAPNS/Options.swift:69`, then in `priv` variable, you'll see private part of the key, in `pub`, you'll see public part of the key